# GDB to dissasemble dynamically-loaded code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gdb

I'm loading binary code dynamically I would like to debug with GDB in assembly.

By using `layout asm`, at the moment of debugging when I reach the following instruction:

```
call *%eax
```

where the register `eax` contains the address of the binary code I have already loaded and that I want GDB to debug. I keep getting the message below every time I try to step into the next instruction by means of `stepi`:

> No function contains program counter for selected frame.

I am already using `set disassemble-next-line on` which is supposed to automatically disassemble the next instruction I step into.

I'm using GDB 7.2. Any suggestions?

Comment: `x/i $eip` or switch to `layout asm`

Comment: @Jester It's already `layout asm`.

Comment: Then you should see the disassembly. Or is it only the error message that bothers you?

Comment: @Jester, what bothers me is that after `call *$eax` I don't see anything other than the error message.

Comment: `x/i $eip` or `display/i $eip` although `layout asm` should just work.

Comment: @Jester, thanks a lot. Now I am able to see `push %ebp` which is for sure the next instruction after the call. The problem is that even If do `stepi` or `nexti` I am not able to move into the next instruction. Somehow it gets "stuck" at `push %ebp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
disassemble $pc,+64
```

(or some other small number instead of 64) to view the next upcoming instructions, irrespective of whether there is debugging information.

`layout asm` should probably do this automatically because it is implicitly limited by the terminal height. This looks like a GDB bug/request for enhancement (but I already see the desired behavior with *GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git* on amd64).